# PrestaShop: How to add custom font in the generated pdf invoice

Tags: fonts, overriding, prestashop, tcpdf, prestashop-1.6

In my online shop I am using PrestaShop 1.6.1.6 , I used Bangla Language for product names. And while generating pdf the fonts are broken that contains bangla letters because no bangla font is there in tcpdf. How can i add any custom font (truetype) in the tcpdf?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the PDFGenerator class, and precisely `$font_by_lang`:

```
class PDFGenerator extends PDFGeneratorCore {
    public function __construct($use_cache = false, $orientation = 'P'){
        // Override the font for your language
        $this->font_by_lang['en'] = 'roboto';
        parent::__construct($use_cache, $orientation);
    }
}
```

Place the `PDFGenerator.php` in this path `prestashop/override/classes/PDF/`

After that you have to place the font and a .php file in `prestashop/tools/tcpdf/fonts, see the other font file for understand how you have to give to tcpdf the font.
Maybe you can use [this site](http://fonts.snm-portal.com/) to convert ttf to tcpdf font files, I've never used but if don't work there are many sites that offer this service.